# Modes of convergence for continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I just wondered about what modes of convergence for continuous functions $f_n:X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces there are.

Of course there is pointwise convergence, which is defineable for arbitrary topological spaces, and compact / uniform convergence, for which (to my knowledge) one would need $Y$ to be a metric space or topological vector space.

But what about the following idea, to say $f_n$ converges to some (continuous) $f:X\rightarrow Y$ iff for $x\in X$ and $U\in{\cal U}(f(x))$ there is $V\in{\cal U}(x)$ and $N>0$ such that $f_n(V)\subseteq U$ whenever $n\ge N$.  This is equivalent with the function $g:X\times(\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n>0\})\rightarrow Y$ defined by $g(x,1/n)=f_n(x)$, $g(x,0)=f(x)$ being continuous.

Is there some name / application for this concept?

Comment: Not commenting on your specific "mode of convergence," but functional analysis targets exactly this issue (what it means for functions to converge to each other). There are all sorts of forms of weak convergence.

Comment: OK, but wouldn't functional analysis deal with topological vector spaces mostly?  For 'my' definition one doesn't need any more structure than the topology on the spaces involved...

Comment: Yes, sure that's a good point, and your mode is interesting - I wonder if you can prove this to be equivalent to pointwise convergence in a TVS (meaning if you start with TVS's). Nonetheless, interesting concept!

Comment: I don't think so, if you take $X,Y={\bf R}$ and $f_n$ such that $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in (-\infty,0]\cup [1/n,\infty)$ but $f_n(x)=1$ somewhere between then $f_n$ is converging pointwise to $0$ but not in the other mode.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot that you would only consider linear functions between vector spaces then \*blush\*...  I will think about it for a moment!  (I leave my previous comment still there because it serves as a simple example for where the two modes differ.)

Comment: I think it is not the same.  Consider the space $c_{00}$ of sequences with all but finitely many members $0$ and the supremum norm.  Then let $f_n:c_{00}\rightarrow {\bf R}$ multiply the first $n$ terms in the a sequence with $0$ and the rest with $n$, $f_n$ is linear and continuous then and converges pointwise to $0$ but not in the other mode.